# Access Denied when creating RDS during init of Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Being new to the platform I've followed the setup tutorial:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

When I tried to created the RDS DB it wouldn't let me with the message:

```
InvalidParameterValue. Access Denied to API Version: API20120423
```

Output in the commandline:

[image]

What could be the reason for this happening?

Comment: Could be due to your AWS Permissions. Are you the root user of the account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can answer 'n' to the question "Create an RDS DB Instance", in this way you should be able to complete the init step of your environment.

Then to create an actual RDS DB go to your AWS console, in the Elastic Beanstalk section you'll find your newly created env. Click on the env and in the "Configuration" page you'll find a "Data tier" section, where you'll be able to create a RDS DB, associating it to your env.